# How to implement Xbox controller in Android app?

Tags: android

I'm developing a app for controlling a vehicle. I want to use a xbox 360 controller. I have a usb otg cable which connects xbox controller and android device.

What do I have to do to handle the controls which I get from the controller?

Comment: there is a doc on android site about usb host programming.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html

Answer (score 2):

found this on https://blog.sagaoftherealms.net/?p=161 (didn't test it already):

> I’ve been working on a few Android games in my spare time. With the
>   rollout of Honeycomb to my Logitech Revue, I’ve been able to finally
>   test these games on it. One of the things I noticed was that the Revue
>   has USB Host support and (wired) Xbox 360 controllers are simply plug
>   and play. Using them is quite simple as well; the button presses are
>   mostly mapped to the key event. The left and right triggers, right
>   directional stick, and analog inputs are not mapped through this
>   method however. The left analog stick and directional pads have their
>   inputs mapped to direction buttons.
>
> ```
> @Override
> public  boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
>      switch(keyCode) {
>           case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_L1:
>           case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_R1:
>           case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_THUMBR:
>           case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_THUMBL: 
>           case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
>           case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
>           case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
>           case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
>           case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_START:
>           case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_MODE://Big button in the middle
>           case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_B: 
>           case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_A:
>           case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_X:
>           case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_Y:
>           default:
>           return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, keyEvent);
>      }
> }
> ```
>
> Of special note, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_B goes back and
>   KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_START pulls up home bar in the default
>   implementation. Also, the “A” button has special behaviors which I
>   don’t fully understand. For the analog controls however, we must
>   override the method onGenericMotionEvent as follows:
>
> ```
> @Override
> public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event) {
>
>     Log.d("Right Trigger Value", event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_RTRIGGER) + "");
>     Log.d("Left Trigger Value", event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_LTRIGGER) + "");
>
>     Log.d("Left Stick X", event.getX() + "");
>     Log.d("Left Stick Y", event.getY() + "");
>
>     Log.d("Right Stick Y", event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_RZ) + "");
>     Log.d("Right Stick X", event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_Z) + ""); 
>
>     return super.onGenericMotionEvent(event);
> }
> ```

Comment: Hey I'm the author of that blog.  Did it work for you?

Comment: I had problems with connecting my controller to my phone. So I wasn't able to test it. But when I need it for a project in the future, I let you know.